# Resolving IEnumerable of generic interfaces from Autofac container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm not sure if this is possible, I've seen some other posts asking similar question but none have a satisfactory answer.

What I want to do is resolve a collection of interfaces with differing generic types from Autofac. So constructor of class would look something like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITestInterface<T>> _testInterfaces;

    public SomeClass(IEnumerable<ITestInterface<T>> testInterfaces)
    {
        _testInterfaces = testInterfaces;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd just like to be able to register each instance individually like so:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<ImplementationA>()
    .As<ITestInterface<A>>();

builder
    .RegisterType<ImplementationB>()
    .As<ITestInterface<B>>();
```

I've tried various combinations of `RegisterGeneric` etc but the Enumerable just keeps coming through empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BenKnoble I updated the question - the enumerable is empty every time.

Comment: It doesn't seem right. **A** obviously doesn't implement **ITestInterface<A>**. Could you show me a sample of class that implements **ITestInterface**?

Comment: In my opinion registering **A** as **ITestInterface<A>** is conceptually wrong! Even if it is possible, it will leads to future errors and misunderstandings

Comment: @Win You guys are right - the code was incorrect. Have fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this after playing with inheritance & generic constraints. The solution I ended up with looks like this:

Base classes / interfaces:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract string IAM { get; }
}

public interface ITestInterface<out T> where T : BaseClass
{
    T GetSomething();
}
```

Implemented classes:

```
public class A : BaseClass
{
    public override string IAM => "I AM TYPE A";
}

public class AInterface : ITestInterface<A>
{
    public A GetSomething()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
    public override string IAM => "I AM TYPE B";
}

public class BInterface : ITestInterface<B>
{
    public B GetSomething()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Class we want to resolve:

```
public interface ISomeClass
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomeClass<T> : ISomeClass where T : BaseClass
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITestInterface<T>> _testInterfaces;

    public SomeClass(IEnumerable<ITestInterface<T>> testInterfaces)
    {
        _testInterfaces = testInterfaces;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        foreach (var t in _testInterfaces)
        {
            var something = t.GetSomething();

            Console.WriteLine(something.IAM);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, Autofac configuration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder
    .RegisterType<SomeClass<BaseClass>>()
    .AsSelf();

builder
    .RegisterType<AInterface>()
    .As<ITestInterface<BaseClass>>();

builder
    .RegisterType<BInterface>()
    .As<ITestInterface<BaseClass>>();

builder
    .RegisterType<SomeClass<BaseClass>>()
    .As<ISomeClass>();

var container = builder.Build();

var x = container.Resolve<ISomeClass>();

x.DoSomething();
```

Outputs:

> I AM TYPE A
>
> I AM TYPE B

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: The key here is the covariance of T in `ITestInterface`, otherwise you can't assign `AInterface` to `ITestInterface<BaseClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

`RegisterGeneric` should work fine :

```
builder.RegisterType<TestImplementationA>()
        .As<ITestInterface<A>>();
builder.RegisterType<TestImplementationB>()
        .As<ITestInterface<B>>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeClass<>))
       .As(typeof(ISomeClass<>));
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<TestImplementationA>()
        .As<ITestInterface<A>>();
builder.RegisterType<TestImplementationB>()
        .As<ITestInterface<B>>();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeClass<>))
       .AsSelf();
```

You will find below a working sample :

```
public interface ISomeClass<T> where T : class
{
    Int32 Count { get; }
}
public class SomeClass<T> : ISomeClass<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITestInterface<T>> _testInterfaces;

    public SomeClass(IEnumerable<ITestInterface<T>> testInterfaces)
    {
        _testInterfaces = testInterfaces;
    }

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this._testInterfaces.Count();
        }
    }
}

public interface ITestInterface {}
public interface ITestInterface<T> : ITestInterface { }
public class A { }
public class B { }
public class TestImplementationA : ITestInterface<A> { }
public class TestImplementationB : ITestInterface<B> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<TestImplementationA>()
               .As<ITestInterface<A>>()
               .As<ITestInterface>();

        builder.RegisterType<TestImplementationB>()
               .As<ITestInterface<B>>()
               .As<ITestInterface>();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeClass<>))
               .As(typeof(ISomeClass<>));

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        var x = container.Resolve<ISomeClass<A>>();

        Console.WriteLine(x.Count);

        var z = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ITestInterface>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the code `SomeClass` is only instantiated with one interface: `TestImplementationA`. Do you know if it's possible to get it instantiated with both A & B? I've tried inheriting A & B from a base class and then resolving `SomeClass<Base>`, but then no classes were injected at all.

Comment: @RagtimeWilly `SomeClass<T>` requires a collection of `ITestInterface<T>`. you can't mix a `ITestInterface<A>`  and a `ITestInterface<B>` on a same `IEnumerable<>`. If you want to mix its, you have to create a base class and declare your dependencies as base class. See my updated sample.