# Autofac inject IEnumerable of generic interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

So, I recognize StackOverflow is littered with this question, but frequently no one explains why they want to do this. I'm hoping that by doing so a better answer floats to the top.

This guy did something close to what I want: [Resolving IEnumerable of generic interfaces from Autofac container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801361/resolving-ienumerable-of-generic-interfaces-from-autofac-container) But not quite.

I recognize `IGenericInterface<ObjectA>` is not equivalent to `IGenericInterface<ObjectB>`.

That being said, I'd love to inject every `IService<T>` into a single constructor so that I can build a lookup. Honestly, I'd like to build an implementation very similar to `DbContext.Set<T>`

A few key players in my problem.

```
public interface IService<TMessage> where TMessage: IContractDTO
{
    IQueryable<TMessage> BuildProjection();
}
```

Currently I'm injecting these one at a time

```
public class SomeController : BaseODataController<SomeEntityDTO>
{
    public SomeController(IControllerServiceContext context, IService<SomeEntityDTO> service)
      : base(context, service)
    {

    }

    //DO STUFF
}
```

`IControllerServiceContext` is a composite interface with `DbContext`, `AppSettings`, and a few other common goodies I want in every controller.

In most cases this is good enough. However occasionally in support of logic for EntityA, I might need to do a quick lookup on B. I'd rather use `IService<SomeEntityB>`'s implementation of `BuildProjections()` than building out a redundancy in Controller A. If I inject each one I have a few that would become an 8 or 9 param constructor this way, for example

SO I got to thinking what if I was able to add an `IServiceLookup` to `IControllerServiceContext` then I would have everything I needed.

I Started down this path:

```
public class ServiceLookup<TContract>: IServiceLookup where TContract: BaseClass, IContractDTO
{

    public ServiceLookup(IEnumerable<IService<TContract>> services)
    {
        //Build _Services
    }

    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _services;

    public IService<TMessage> Service<TMessage>() where TMessage : class, IContractDTO
    {
        return (IService<TMessage>)(GetService(typeof(TMessage)));
    }

    private object GetService(Type type)
    {
        _services.TryGetValue(type, out var service);

        return service;
    }
}
```

For obvious reasons this can't be done with the current constructor.

But is there a way to get the dictionary that I do want, either by `IIndex` or an `IEnumerable` that I can build that dictionary of `<type, object>` where object is my various `IService<T>`?

Service lookup was built based on reading the `DbContext` code and simplifying the logic for `DbContext.Set`, which is also driven by `IDictionary<Type, object>`.

If through some kind of resolver parameter I can get all the `IService<T>`s, Extract the `T` types, and add them to that list, I'm off to the races.

*Edit*: I recognize I could inject the parameters I need to build each service 
into `ServiceLookup` and manually build my list, and that may even be the better answer... but if I can do it without all that, it would be a lot more robust, and I'm fundamentally *curious* if it is possible

*Edit2*:  What I want to be able to do in implementation would look like this:

```
public SomeController(IControllerServiceContext context, IServiceLookup lookup)
      : base(context, service)
{
    public SomeMethod() {
       var x = lookup.Service<EntityOneDTO>().BuildProjections().FirstOrDefault();
       var y = lookup.Service<EntityTwoDTO>().BuildProjections().FirstOrDefault();

    //Do Logic that requires both EntityOne and EntityTwo  
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the point of what you are trying to do. Based on what I understand, I made this sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/nGlqm1 and it works. Could you explain more what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand - I added some details. 

Your example is a bit backwards from where im going.


I have Service1:  IService<Message1>
and Service2:  IService<Message2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following types :

```
public class MessageA { }
public class MessageB { }

public interface IService<TMessage> { }
public class ServiceA : IService<MessageA> { }
public class ServiceB : IService<MessageB> { }
```

And you have a controller and you want to get a `IService<MessageA>` based on whatever you want.

The first solution would be to inject all `IService` you may required :

```
public class Controller
{
    public Controller(IService<MessageA> serviceA, IService<MessageB> serviceB)
    {
        this._serviceA = serviceA;
        this._serviceB = serviceB; 
    }

    private readonly IService<MessageA> _serviceA;
    private readonly IService<MessageB> _serviceB;

    public void Do()
    {
        IService<MessageA> serviceA = this._serviceA;
    }
}
```

It works if you have few message type but not if you have more than few.

because `IService<T>` is generic and `Do` there is no easy way to mix both world. The first solution would be to introduce a non generic interface

```
public interface IService { }
public interface IService<TMessage> : IService { }
```

and register these type like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IService<MessageA>>().As<IService>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().As<IService<MessageB>>().As<IService>();
```

Then you can have an `IEnumerable<IService>`. Something like that :

```
public interface IServiceLookup
{
    IService<TMessage> Get<TMessage>();
}
public class ServiceLookup : IServiceLookup
{
    public ServiceLookup(IEnumerable<IService> services)
    {
        this._services = services
            .ToDictionary(s => s.GetType()
                .GetInterfaces()
                .First(i => i.IsGenericType 
                            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IService<>))
                .GetGenericArguments()[0], 
                          s => s);
    }
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IService> _services;

    public IService<TMessage> Get<TMessage>()
    {
        // you should check for type missing, etc. 
        return (IService<TMessage>)this._services[typeof(TMessage)];
    }
}
```

and then inject `IServiceLookup` inside your controller.

The drawback of this solution is that it create instances of all your IService, to avoid that you can inject `IEnumerable<Func<IService>>`

Another solution would be to inject `IComponentContext` to `ServiceLookup`. `ComponentContext` is an *Autofac* type from where you can resolve services.

```
public class ServiceLookup : IServiceLookup
{
    public ServiceLookup(IComponentContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;

    public IService<TMessage> Get<TMessage>()
    {
        return this._context.Resolve<IService<TMessage>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try when I return to the office!